# Being precise about contour integrals when dealing with branch-cuts and singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

In this paper https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/93357#page/65/mode/1up of Landau he wants to evaluate $$\int _{2-iT}^{2+iT}\frac {x^s\log (s-1)}{s^2}\hspace {10mm}(1)$$
(page 755). He sets up a keyhole-type contour path, something like $$\int _{\text {path from $2+iT$ to $1/2$}}+\int _{L_1}+\int _{L_2}+\int _{\text {path from $1/2$ to $2-iT$}}\hspace {10mm}(2)$$ where $L_1,L_2$ are paths between 1/2 and 1, essentially on the real line. He then applies Cauchy's Residue Theorem - he says (1) and (2) are equal.

I feel I understand the general idea, and understand that we choose a different argument for $\log (s-1)$ when we take the path the second time, and that it's this $2\pi i$ increment that gives us a main term. (I also understand that each individual integral exists because $\log $ growth means we can take the integrals up to the singular point.) Still, when I'm pushed to write down *concretely* and *precisely* what's happening then I find I can't do it.

Specifically:

1.Cauchy's Integral Theorem, as far as I know, is a statement about functions on a *subset* of $\mathbb C$. In that case, what exactly is the subset we take above? Is it $\mathbb C-\mathbb R^{\leq 0}$ for example? It could well be that I'm oversimplifying and that it's not just a subset.

2. What precisely are the paths $L_1$ and $L_2$? Are they literally on the real axis or are they just above and below, with an $\epsilon $ argument that's not written down explicitly?
3. Does the path self-intersect along the real axis, and if so how do we apply Cauchy's Theorem?

I'd like it if someone could tell me precisely where/how Cauchy's Integral Theorem is being applied, perhaps having to be very careful about the exact statement.

Sorry for being so pedantic it just seems to be something I need to get clear! Thanks:)

Comment: They are two paths approximating the real axis from above and below. This treatment is quite common in the theory of special functions back then.

Comment: what does "approximating" mean? can you write down literally what those paths are? (again sorry for being insisting here:D)

Answer (score 0):

When $\log$ is meant to take the principal value, the function $s^{-2}x^s\log(s-1)$ is holomorphic and one-valued inside and on the contour described as follows.

[image: Contour illustration]

Consequently, Cauchy's theorem applies, and notice that the integral over the circle around $s=1$ vanishes when the radius of the circle tends to zero, so you will obtain the desired result.

Comment: i get the idea, but can you write down for me *precisely* what the application of cauchy's theorem is? on what domain exactly, and what path exactly? (starting with your black contour as 1 and going round, i'm not worried about contours 1,2,3,7,8. but i'd like to see a concrete definition of contour 4 for example)

Comment: i think i always assumed cauchy was applied to simply-connected. but we can apply it to any open set provided the curve shrinks to a point right? and that's the version we're applying? i think that was my problem

Comment: The cut plane is simply connected.

Comment: so those paths are not on the real line?

Comment: They are not meant to be on the real line. They lie on the real line only after you take limits.

Comment: ok, then i think it's a different example. i think i understand those arguments. the one in my post has the contours literally on the line (as i understand)

Comment: also, there's no circle about zero in the example i gave. i understand the examples you mention, it's the one in landau's paper i don't understand

Comment: When you make the radius go to zero, the integral over the circle vanishes, and the segments will approach the real line. There are similar treatments in Chapter 3 of Titchmarsh’s book on $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: i agree your circle goes to zero, and the ones in titchmarsh's book. i was talking specifically about the contour in the link in my post, where there is no circle and where the paths are literally on the real line.

Comment: That's because Landau skipped steps and shows you the limiting contour directly in the text

Comment: you are 100% sure of that?

Comment: I am pretty sure of this because you will arrive at the same result by taking the limits

Comment: ok, if he means he's applying it *in* the domain and then he takes a limit, i guess i'm ok. thanks:)